# Facebook Javascript SDK: First time logging in

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm currently integrating Facebook with my website using the Javascript SDK. I've got the login portion working well. The only thing I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way to tell if it was the first time the user logged into my website using their Facebook credientials. I tried subscribing to auth.login, but that didn't seem to have any information about that. Is there a flag anywhere that lets me know this? Or another way to go about looking this up? I realize I could do some server side code, but I'd prefer to stay away from that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something facebook will do for you. You will need to keep track yourself. It wouldn't be as accurate as server-side, but maybe you could just use a cookie on the user to detect if they have used it before? If you only want it for showing additional info to new users then that might be a more straight forward solution rather than saving it server-side.

Comment: Hi Abby, thanks for the response. I thought about using cookies too, but, yeah, they're just not that reliable. I'm starting to think a server side solution is unavoidable. Maybe I'll drop the Facebook devs a note and let them know that this would be helpful.